# Deploy Java application with Netbeans to remote OrangePi

Tags: java, netbeans, raspberry-pi, orange-pi

I followed the tutorial on youtube how to deploy a Java app to remote RaspberryPi and tryed the same with the OrangePi. The problem I have is that I can't select the remote JVM from the Netbeans..

Here are some screen shoots:
[image]

When I try to select a Runtime platform I have only the default JDK1.8 which is installed on the local machine (Project Platform) and the Remote platform (OrangePI) is missing (I can't select it from the list).

[image]

I followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EXy5Ysp3yp4&t=301s

The only difference is that I'am using root as user...

regards
Ferguson

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that on OrangePi was Java 1.7 and in Netbeans 1.8...